# A problem with creating directories in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am writing a code in tcl using windows. When I try to create a folder using this command

```
set FileName "GVOutPut";
file mkdir $FileName;
```

i get this error:

```
can't create directory "GVOutPut": permission denied
    while executing
"file mkdir $FileName"
```

how could i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you able to manually create the folder?

Comment: yeah, I can create it manually

Answer (score 2):

You should check that the current directory (`puts [pwd]`) is the directory where you expect the new directory to be created in instead of being somewhere where normal users can't write by default. It is *very* easy for that to be different in a GUI program than for a text program; the defaults vary (due to the different ways that they're launched by the OS). It often pays to use full pathnames in your programs, or to make things all relative to a known location. You can use the `cd` command to set the current directory.

Alternatively, launch the program from an elevated shell. But you probably don't want that option as it has a lot of non-trivial consequences.

Comment: i checked the current directory and it gave me a different one from what i expected as you said. thanks for your help :)